# Nodegit cloning not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, nodegit

I'm trying to use the [Nodegit](http://www.nodegit.org/) plugin to [clone](http://www.nodegit.org/api/clone/) some git repos into a directory called 'tmp' so I can do things with the actual folder (upload it to a server). Here's my code:

```
var git = require('nodegit');

var repos = [some https repo urls]

var options = {
    remoteCallbacks: {
        certificateCheck: function() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
};

for(i = 0; i<repos.length; i++){
    git.Clone(repos[i], './tmp', options).catch(function(err) { console.error(err); } );
}
```

All it does is create an empty directory called 'tmp' for a split second and deletes it. The errors I get are `./tmp' exists and is not an empty directory` (but it does not exist?) and `authentication required but no callback set`. Anyone know how to fix these?

Comment: I haven't used the project, but looking at the docs NodeGit seems to support promises, so add an error case handler with something like `git.Clone(repos[i], './tmp).catch(function(err) { console.log(err); } );` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @orbitbot. I added the error case and updated the op with the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @johnhaley81 mentioned in gitter, you should checkout the test code [here](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/master/test/tests/clone.js#L38-L53). Overriding the `certificateCheck` should resolve `The SSL certificate is invalid` error.

The `./tmp` error makes sense, because you are trying to clone multiple repositories into the same directory.